# MySQl Query Execution Plan

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL optimizer changes the execution plan based on the WHERE condition ?
   If I add one extra column for the comparison in WHERE condition , does it affect query execution plan ?

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXPLAIN <your query>` to tell you what the system will do. Adding an extra column can definitely change the way it's interpreted, however.

There's a page on using `EXPLAIN` in the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html